# Excel Mac: If these two arguments are true then count/sum the number of unique ID#s

Tags: excel

This is what I am trying to figure out:

*IF date in cell matches dates in range
and
If name in cell matches names in range
then 
count/sum the number of unique ID#s*

This is the formula I have:

```
=IF(Data!A:A=E10,(IF(Data!D:D=D11,(IF(Data!D:D=D11,SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(Data!C:C,Data!C:C)>0,1)),"ERROR3")),"ERROR2")),"ERROR1")
```

It does not output the correct info. It either counts all the unique IDs or it Errors out when it should have a result.

I hope I am on the right track, thank you for any help.

[Sample dataset:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQwOq.png)

Comment: So what is the question?  Where is the problem?

Comment: It does not output the correct info. It either counts all the unique IDs or it Errors out when it should have a result.

Comment: Are you trying to post sample data? Paste text into the question or post a screenshot or a link to a file on Dropbox, Onedrive or similar.

Comment: Sorry about that, too much multi-tasking over here.

Comment: I made the edit to the post. When I click on the sample dataset it brings up the screenshot for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((B$2:B$10>=E2)*(B$2:B$10<=F2))/
     (COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10, ">="&E2, B$2:B$10, "<="&F2, A$2:A$10, A$2:A$10)+(B$2:B$10<E2)+(B$2:B$10>F2)))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula attempt has crashed my comp several times today. Part of it is the size of the dataset but still, I feel your pain. I have tried countifs and sumif prior to this ugly if within if but to no avail either. I know that the SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(Data!C:C,Data!C:C)>0,1) works to get the total count of unique job#s but everything else has been a mess

Comment: @A.S.H - you need the additions to the denominator to avoid div/0 errors.

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that the question was pretty confusing before you posted an image of the data, as it appears that the term "dates in range" was completely misleading. In fact you are trying to match exact dates, not *"ranges of date"*.

`FREQUENCY` is useful to detect the first appearance of an item in a column, but unfortunately, this "artificial trick" is not flexible enough to be mixed easily with other criteria, and most importantly `FREQUENCY` is not array friendly.

There's another method to achieve you goal, which is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Data!$A$1:$A$24=E$10)*Data!$C$1:$C$24=$D11))/
COUNTIFS(Data!$A$1:$A$24,Data!$A$1:$A$24,Data!$B$1:$B$24,Data!$B$1:$B$24,Data!$C$1:$C$24,Data!$C$1:$C$24))
```

You can enter this formula in `E11` in your sample image and copy/paste in the whole matrix.

The denominator of the formula (the second line) generates an array that counts for each row the number of duplicates.

The numerator sets the criteria. Since each successful row will repeat as many times in the numerator and in the denominator, each matching row will be counted for a total of one.

As a result, we obtain the number of "unique rows" that match the criteria.

The formula should not use complete columns such as `A:A` etc, make the effort to limit it to a reasonable number of rows, say `A1:A999` or so. Complex formulas involving arrays must avoid as much as possible entire columns.